# JSON Serialisation Issue

Tags: c#, json

I am having some issues with trying to de-serialise a json string into an object and i cannot figure out the issue.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTiYAS

I have created this dotnetfiddle to try and figure it out but i cannot see the issue and don't understand the error.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Json string below

```
                [
               {
                  "data":{
                     "status":"document.completed",
                     "name":"PARQ and Waiver",
                     "recipients":[
                        {
                           "first_name":"Chris",
                           "last_name":"Smith",
                           "email":"chris@domainname.com",
                           "role":"",
                           "recipient_type":"CC",
                           "has_completed":true,
                           "id":"9TtfZ8FE2XDaZi3t7AfKnj"
                        },
                        {
                           "first_name":"Chris",
                           "last_name":"Smith",
                           "email":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "role":"Member",
                           "recipient_type":"signer",
                           "has_completed":true,
                           "id":"NQXY5GZkGXozUu4apNEV2Z"
                        }
                     ],
                     "date_modified":"2016-10-04T05:50:07.484635Z",
                     "fields":[
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"",
                           "uuid":"Kzm9GTTomzao3fmcC5U968",
                           "value":"dasdasd",
                           "name":"Textfield"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"",
                           "uuid":"3KUNJTsGnSA3PUiPTnKqVo",
                           "value":"3asdas",
                           "name":"EmergencyContactName"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"",
                           "uuid":"TcDrKky4ahtU5BvgYgqiCZ",
                           "value":"12312",
                           "name":"MemberICNumber"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"MemberName",
                           "uuid":"XjNFVWoG8gPhFGEVnHXCrE",
                           "value":"Chris Smith",
                           "name":"MemberName"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Signature",
                           "uuid":"ZWRPXG6UUP86A8FvCRmpcZ",
                           "value":{

                           },
                           "name":"Signature"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Signature",
                           "uuid":"bLercwpbgqKFcLG3TTqsRD",
                           "value":{

                           },
                           "name":"Signature"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"CurrentDate",
                           "uuid":"rFpaSpQXEsuu4KqcUS9MJT",
                           "value":"2016-10-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                           "name":"CurrentDate"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"EmployeeName",
                           "uuid":"GoqRq7WoRad3umjcgtCA6H",
                           "value":"Christopher Smith",
                           "name":"EmployeeName"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"krEjqFZXNjYXAhT3d4eabU",
                           "value":{

                           },
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"Aa3AeywRfrkco7hyodL83V",
                           "value":true,
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"o83dM7bE956W7b2Pek9LuR",
                           "value":{

                           },
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"DrkJrj8LgZJLDTQvmeLt6S",
                           "value":{

                           },
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"QLvkZPJzcK4QmCunbsuJMm",
                           "value":true,
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"UusciRwckWig6fAzGPqvdM",
                           "value":true,
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"SfwCUPfsWP4ufMdbPUsoYN",
                           "value":{

                           },
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"F4vn8B39cZcdzmoycaMk7d",
                           "value":{

                           },
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"BxcC5Gme3v6d6xAM2o6Euh",
                           "value":true,
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"fRCKZMkUQuT5roh9mG98JG",
                           "value":{

                           },
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"UgxwN3BmJvZm7NZFvnMExi",
                           "value":true,
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"Ah8qEhU8wvkFA7nFJmVzMA",
                           "value":{

                           },
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"KrmFKD5vM8fzeGuDHmAqLe",
                           "value":true,
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        },
                        {
                           "assignee":"chris+uktest@domainname.com",
                           "title":"Checkbox",
                           "uuid":"x5VJRphNSZRgS73bZxSBCm",
                           "value":true,
                           "name":"Checkbox"
                        }
                     ],
                     "tags":[

                     ],
                     "sent_by":{
                        "email":"chris@domainname.com",
                        "first_name":"Chris",
                        "last_name":"Smith",
                        "id":"QWYXpQw4zyd2y3U2py8cc9",
                        "avatar":null
                     },
                     "created_by":{
                        "email":"chris@domainname.com",
                        "first_name":"Chris",
                        "last_name":"Smith",
                        "id":"QWYXpQw4zyd2y3U2py8cc9",
                        "avatar":null
                     },
                     "tokens":[

                     ],
                     "action_date":"2016-10-04T05:50:07.783684",
                     "action_by":{
                        "first_name":"Chris",
                        "last_name":"Smith",
                        "id":"JAct5Xj5N6WUbCf8KRpFFc",
                        "email":"chris+uktest@domainname.com"
                     },
                     "date_created":"2016-10-04T05:50:07.484600Z",
                     "id":"uFLyzUS68hkyTu2QFgLmtN",
                     "metadata":{

                     }
                  },
                  "event":"recipient_completed"
               }
            ]
```

The code used to deserialize the string is :

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;      
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;                 
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "[{\"data\": {\"status\": \"document.completed\", \"name\": \"PARQ and Waiver (Final 15 September 2016)\", \"recipients\": [{\"first_name\": \"Chris\", \"last_name\": \"Pettigrew\", \"email\": \"chris@ritualgym.com\", \"role\": \"\", \"recipient_type\": \"CC\", \"has_completed\": true, \"id\": \"nsCaT2VWLnctgKge77ZfQL\"}, {\"first_name\": \"Chris\", \"last_name\": \"Pettigrew\", \"email\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"role\": \"Member\", \"recipient_type\": \"signer\", \"has_completed\": true, \"id\": \"AHXfWQuH8MkbL9vxzfhtsc\"}], \"date_modified\": \"2016-10-04T07:43:14.353443Z\", \"fields\": [{\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"\", \"uuid\": \"pB5cNLi7nm3LMNBChbkURT\", \"value\": \"asdasd\", \"name\": \"Textfield\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"\", \"uuid\": \"HawALj7sghbpwKQG4Ft949\", \"value\": \"asdasd\", \"name\": \"EmergencyContactName\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"\", \"uuid\": \"hmMLPtCfEYGDE8QwehCbVj\", \"value\": \"12313\", \"name\": \"MemberICNumber\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"MemberName\", \"uuid\": \"V66jyajqeBDmPF9mzFJA86\", \"value\": \"Chris Pettigrew\", \"name\": \"MemberName\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Signature\", \"uuid\": \"GhGkMnm6GnfaZ5yeV4GtVR\", \"value\": {}, \"name\": \"Signature\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Signature\", \"uuid\": \"hjGimFc83PwZoeMXdFEVQc\", \"value\": {}, \"name\": \"Signature\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"CurrentDate\", \"uuid\": \"jRqpik4oia3nMN8Fp4Bk5S\", \"value\": \"2016-10-04T00:00:00.000Z\", \"name\": \"CurrentDate\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"EmployeeName\", \"uuid\": \"4bdjuVw6BhhuPxu8cetRnV\", \"value\": \"Christopher Pettigrew\", \"name\": \"EmployeeName\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"tvx2UBJWQvktdtuighyt67\", \"value\": {}, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"oB5S2Qc3uUkJKL9JZxUbpa\", \"value\": true, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"Z3nSEm3t7CYa674TSA3A9i\", \"value\": {}, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"H7BiW7Tuow8qhnt3yauDKH\", \"value\": {}, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"mWjfHa5NHRxdWXSaUwE3HG\", \"value\": true, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"hS7xw28cCwkybVpL8Jji9F\", \"value\": true, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"NX9swWbGcjUky2uXoVy8o3\", \"value\": {}, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"WU3xPDzsuxnZv6sMQ7uoLg\", \"value\": {}, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"UavefJS7JjvFnRc3oRMRA6\", \"value\": true, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"cBzK94gzweDU7BcmDXoCn6\", \"value\": {}, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"VsHp3MaHcQtroCNLPwsRPW\", \"value\": true, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"qz9gChVGDim5BGT8ojbReR\", \"value\": {}, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"sUM4HB5BozZxJxoUEJ5CxH\", \"value\": true, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}, {\"assignee\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\", \"title\": \"Checkbox\", \"uuid\": \"aZuXSaeM6LoMmDswJ2oUBT\", \"value\": true, \"name\": \"Checkbox\"}], \"tags\": [], \"sent_by\": {\"email\": \"chris@ritualgym.com\", \"first_name\": \"Chris\", \"last_name\": \"Pettigrew\", \"id\": \"QWYXpQw4zyd2y3U2py8cc9\", \"avatar\": null}, \"created_by\": {\"email\": \"chris@ritualgym.com\", \"first_name\": \"Chris\", \"last_name\": \"Pettigrew\", \"id\": \"QWYXpQw4zyd2y3U2py8cc9\", \"avatar\": null}, \"tokens\": [], \"action_date\": \"2016-10-04T07:43:14.669400\", \"action_by\": {\"first_name\": \"Chris\", \"last_name\": \"Pettigrew\", \"id\": \"JAct5Xj5N6WUbCf8KRpFFc\", \"email\": \"chris+uktest@ritualgym.com\"}, \"date_created\": \"2016-10-04T07:43:14.353410Z\", \"id\": \"8QnPa8jUHrF7RNf5s2HSVD\", \"metadata\": {}}, \"event\": \"recipient_completed\"}]";

    Notification response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notification>(json);
    }
}

    public class Notification
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Document Document { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("event")]
        public string Event { get; set; }
    }

public class Document
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recipients")]
        public Recipient[] Recipients { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date_modified")]
        public string DateModified { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fields")]
        public Fields[] Fields { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tags")]
        public string[] Tags { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sent_by")]
        public User SendBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("created_by")]
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tokens")]
        public Token[] Tokens { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("action_date")]
        public string ActionDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("action_by")]
        public User ActionBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date_created")]
        public string DateCreated { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("metadata")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; }
    }
    public class Fields
    {
        [JsonProperty("assignee")]
        public string Assignee { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("uuid")]
        public string UUID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Recipient
    {
        [JsonProperty("first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("role")]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recipient_type")]
        public string RecipientType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("has_completed")]
        public bool HasCompleted { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Token
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value{ get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("avatar")]
        public string Avatar { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  fiddle is no help

Comment: Post the actual code and problem in the question itself. Adding a link to a fiddle that hasn't loaded after 1 minute  is of no help at all. In any case, you seem to have an array with a single object that has a *lot* of deeply nested properties.

Comment: Your variable is not called `json`, it's called `jsonString`.

Comment: You declared `recipients` in model as a `Recipient[]` but your JSON statement is object (on website) and list here. I don't understand why you put two different versions of JSON.

Comment: the JSON is the same as far as i know..i haven't changed it from the POST from my endpoint.  Have updated the string reference..this isn't the issue..

Comment: if you read the errors, you would get what is wrong.... `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' 1[Recipient]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.`

Comment: Do you mean the who JSON or the recipient bit?  this i cannot alter as the inbound json object is not under my control.  Could you give me an example on what object to change it to?

Comment: according to this error, your JSON used in the variable `json` is missing square brackets around recipients, while the original JSON doesn't

Comment: I have corrected this in my example but i now get another similar error:  Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Notification' because the type r.....deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: your variable of type `Notification` is an object. Therefore what you want to parse is an object too and not a list. i.e. in your JSON [...] is a list or some collection. either convert your json like `var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Notification>>(json);` or change the json, so that it is not a list of Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this model class to deserialize json object.

```
public class Recipient
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string recipient_type { get; set; }
    public bool has_completed { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string assignee { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class SentBy
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object avatar { get; set; }
}

public class CreatedBy
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object avatar { get; set; }
}

public class ActionBy
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
}

public class Data
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Recipient> recipients { get; set; }
    public string date_modified { get; set; }
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
    public List<object> tags { get; set; }
    public SentBy sent_by { get; set; }
    public CreatedBy created_by { get; set; }
    public List<object> tokens { get; set; }
    public string action_date { get; set; }
    public ActionBy action_by { get; set; }
    public string date_created { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public string @event { get; set; }
}
```

Or try check this website http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: You assume that the OP's code doesn't have a typo like eg using the wrong variable name ....